# Border added to top of iframe when running in mobile Chrome (Device Emulation or Android)

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

I have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8767mg92/embedded/result/) that has a sticky header that is above an iframe. When running in Chrome with device emulation (e.g. Google Nexus 7 or even running on Chrome for Android), a border appears above the top content:

[image: top border]

When I scroll the content, the border disappears. When I'm not running device emulation, running on Chrome for Android, or in Firefox, the border doesn't appear.

Here's the snippet:

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {      
    padding: 0 0;
    margin: 0 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container-brand {
    background: blue;
}

.container-shell {
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.brand {
    height: 40px;
}

.shell {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-brand">
    <div class="brand">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-shell">
    <iframe class="shell" srcdoc="<style>html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }</style><div style='background: black; width: 10000px; height: 10000px;'></div>" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get rid of this border? I've of course tried `* { border: none !important; }` on both the source document as well as the `iframe`. I suspect that this is a bug in Chrome because when I increase the width of the Device Emulation size it eventually goes away (e.g. resizing Google Nexus 7 to 980px wide removes the border).

Comment: Did you try css `border:0px;`? Using HTML attributes have been deprecated for a long time.

Comment: @Daniel Yes I did, but it didn't work.